# Pass query params to Erlang HTTP Request

Tags: http, erlang, url-parameters

I'm trying to send parameters with an URL, like `http://localhost:3000/register?name=Chris&job=typist`. I can send that all at once as a string with `httpc:request`, but I can't find a function to put the query parameters in the URL(given a dictionary).

Is there another HTTP library I should be using that has this capability?

I'd like to give it a root URL with a hash/dictonary/map (in json {"a" : "b", "c" : "d"}) that then appends it correctly to the end of the url. For example, given `"www.facebook.com"` and `[{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}]` would give `"www.facebook.com?a=b&c=d"`.

Here is a similar question for Ruby: [Ruby: How to turn a hash into HTTP parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798710/how-to-turn-a-ruby-hash-into-http-params)

Comment: What do you mean « put the query params in the url » ?

Comment: Just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure *exactly* what you mean by "hash", but if you'd like to construct a query string from tuples, that is a fairly straitforward task.

I'm not familiar with a method in httpc to provide the functionality you desire. You can write a wrapper around request/4 very easily, similar to this.

(This program is hastily constructed to give you the idea, forgive any errors).

```
request(Method, Domain, {Path, Query, Fragment}, HTTPOptions, Options) -> 
    QueryString = lists:flatten([Path,
                   case Query of "" -> ""; _ -> [$? | Query] end,
                   case Fragment of "" -> ""; _ -> [$# | Fragment] end]);
    Request = concat(Domain, QueryString);
    httpc:request(Method, {Request, []}, HTTPOptions, Options).
```

You can invoke it like

`request(get, "http://www.example.com", {"/path", "", "bar?baz}, HTTPOptions, Options)`

Comment: I'd like to give it a root URL with a hash/dictonary/map (in json {"a" : "b", "c" : "d"}) that then appends it correctly to the end of the url. => "www.facebook.com?a=b&c=d"

Comment: Erlang's string processing capabilities may be lacking, but I think you could write a method to do that quite easily. 

If you can't figure it out, consult a library like mochijson2.

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
test(URL,QP)->URL++"?"++loop(QP,[]).

loop([{A,B}],QP)->QP++A++"="++B;
loop([{A,B}|T],QP)->loop(T,QP++A++"="++B++"&").
```

call `test("www.facebook.com",[{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}]).`
it returns `"www.facebook.com?a=b&c=d"`.