# RoR Net::HTTP post error undefined method `bytesize'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, cookies

I am currently banging my head against the wall repeatedly until I get passed this issue. I'm using ruby-1.9.3-p194 and Rails. I'm attempting to make a post request which I can do fine with Net::HTTP.post_form, but I can't use that here because I need to set a cookie in the header. http.post is erroring saying

```
"undefined method `bytesize' for #<Hash:0xb1b6c04>"
```

because I guess it's trying to perform some operation on the data being sent.

Does anyone have some kind of fix or work around?

Thanks

```
headers = {'Cookie' => 'mycookieinformationinhere'}
uri = URI.parse("http://asite.com/where/I/want/to/go")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
response = http.post(uri.path, {'test' => 'test'}, headers)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`bytesize`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-bytesize) method is on `String`, not `Hash`. That's your first clue. The second clue is the documentation for [`Net::HTTP#post`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-post):

> **post(path, data, initheader = nil, dest = nil)**
>
> Posts `data` (must be a String) to `path`. `header` must be a Hash like { ‘Accept’ => ‘/’, … }.

You're trying to pass a Hash, `{'test' => 'test'}`, to `post` where it expects to see a `String`. I think you want something more like this:

```
http.post(uri.path, 'test=test', headers)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798710/how-to-turn-a-ruby-hash-into-http-params