# ruby building hash from url

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, what is an efficient way to construct a Hash from a request path like:

```
/1/resource/23/subresource/34
```

into a hash that looks like this:

```
{'1' => { 'resource' => { '23' => 'subresource' => { '34' => {} } } }
```

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798710/how-to-turn-a-ruby-hash-into-http-params

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It seems like a very awkward way to refer to a path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
path = "/1/resource/23/subresource/34"
path.scan(/[^\/]+/).inject(hash = {}) { |h,e| h[e] = {} }

hash
=> {"1"=>{"resource"=>{"23"=>{"subresource"=>{"34"=>{}}}}}}
```

Comment: The same, but if we go in reverse order: `path.scan(/[^\/]+/).reverse.inject({}) { |h,e| {e => h} }`. Might be a little more clear, and anyway, it is a one-liner: it already returns what we want.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution seems like the simplest thing to do. This isn't the prettiest, but it works:

```
def hashify(string)
  k,v = string.gsub(/^\//, '').split('/', 2)  
  { k => v.nil? ? {} : hashify(v) }  
end
```

There may be edge cases it doesn't handle correctly (probably are) but it satisfies the example you've given.