# Ruby URI: build URI with "param[]=value" for array params

Tags: ruby, net-http

I'm trying to query an API (lichess API). And I can't get the params to be correctly taken into account, because `URI` formats the URL not in the expected format for array params.

The expected format is this one: `curl https://explorer.lichess.ovh/lichess?ratings[]=2200&ratings[]=2500`. So the `ratings` params is an Array of values, and the url should be using `ratings[]=value`.

I'm currently generating my URI like this, [as per the doc](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html):

```
base = "https://explorer.lichess.ovh/master"
params = {
  ratings: [1600, 1800]
}

uri = URI(base)
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
```

But this generate the URL like this: `https://explorer.lichess.ovh/master?ratings=1600&ratings=1800`... which is not the expected format, and is not understood by Lichess API.

Does Ruby provide any built-in way to generate the params in the expected format, or will I need to build the URL manually (which feels like revinventing the wheel)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails/ActiveSupport has a [to_query](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/to_query) method which will do what you want.

```
2.1.5 :010 > params.to_query
 => "ratings%5B%5D=1600&ratings%5B%5D=1800"
```

Also, have a look at [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11251654/7987708) which explains why `URI.encode_www_form` doesn't return square brackets.